# Xcode error - Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sigabrt

I am creating a simple RSS application and I am not that good in Objective-c. The application will always build successful and there is no errors or warnings, in the UITableView which reads the RSS, whenever i press the cells it will terminate and in the main.m this thread will come "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" in this line:

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

The information of my app:

The app is created by Xcode version: 4.3.1
The app was created from the "Master-Detail Application" template for iPhone and on a MacBook.
The debugger I am using is LLDB and my iPhone simulator is 5.1
I am using Storyboard

Here is the Main.m:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {
       return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

The AppDelegate.h is:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {

    UIWindow *window;
    UINavigationController *navigationController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;

@end
```

My AppDelegate.m is:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"




#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MasterViewController.h"


@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize navigationController;


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Application lifecycle

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    // Override point for customization after app launch    

    [window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}


- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Save data if appropriate
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Memory management

- (void)dealloc {
    [navigationController release];
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

This is the console message:

```
2012-03-17 17:32:29.498 Rahnavard[1862:12e03] fetch rss
2012-03-17 17:33:01.212 Rahnavard[1862:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/hassantavari/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/48090189-E17C-40CF-9BF1-ACA18FC0B02B/Rahnavard.app> (loaded)' with name 'DetailViewController''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x16e4022 0x1875cd6 0x168ca48 0x168c9b9 0x366638 0x20c1fc 0x20c779 0x20c99b 0x20cd11 0x21e8fd 0x21eaef 0x21edbb 0x21f85f 0x21fe06 0x21fa24 0x393c 0x1d65c5 0x1d67fa 0xa6b85d 0x16b8936 0x16b83d7 0x161b790 0x161ad84 0x161ac9b 0x15cd7d8 0x15cd88a 0x145626 0x26a2 0x2615)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

Here is were the fetch RSS:

```
-(void)fetchRss
{   
    NSLog(@"fetch rss");
    NSData* xmlData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: kRSSUrl] ];
    NSError *error;

    GDataXMLDocument* doc = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:xmlData options:0 error:&error];

    if (doc != nil) {
        self.loaded = YES;

        GDataXMLNode* title = [[[doc rootElement] nodesForXPath:@"channel/title" error:&error] objectAtIndex:0];
        [self.delegate updatedFeedTitle: [title stringValue] ];

        NSArray* items = [[doc rootElement] nodesForXPath:@"channel/item" error:&error];
        NSMutableArray* rssItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[items count] ];

        for (GDataXMLElement* xmlItem in items) {
            [rssItems addObject: [self getItemFromXmlElement:xmlItem] ];
        }

        [self.delegate performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updatedFeedWithRSS:) withObject:rssItems waitUntilDone:YES];
    } else {
        [self.delegate performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(failedFeedUpdateWithError:) withObject:error waitUntilDone:YES];
    }

    [doc autorelease];
    [xmlData release];
}
```

MasterViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "RSSLoader.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"


@interface MasterViewController : UITableViewController<RSSLoaderDelegate> {

    RSSLoader* rss;
    NSMutableArray* rssItems;

}



@end
```

MasterViewController.m:

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"

#import "DetailViewController.h"




@implementation MasterViewController

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.title = @"RAHNAVARD";
    self.navigationItem.prompt = @"LATEST NEWS";
    rssItems = nil;
    rss = nil;

    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
    [self.tableView setIndicatorStyle:UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite];

    //self.tableView.tableHeaderView = [[TableHeaderView alloc] initWithText:@"fetching rss feed"];

}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if (rss==nil) {
        rss = [[RSSLoader alloc] init];
        rss.delegate = self;
        [rss load];
    }
}

/*
 - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
 [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
 }
 */
/*
 - (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
 [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
 }
 */

/*
 // Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
 // Return YES for supported orientations.
 return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
 }
 */


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source

// Customize the number of sections in the table view.
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}


// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (rss.loaded == YES) {
        return [rssItems count]*2;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)getLoadingTableCellWithTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
{
    static NSString *LoadingCellIdentifier = @"LoadingCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:LoadingCellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:LoadingCellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = @"Loading...";

    UIActivityIndicatorView* activity = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    [activity startAnimating];
    [cell setAccessoryView: activity];
    [activity release];

    return cell;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)getTextCellWithTableView:(UITableView *)tableView atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *TextCellIdentifier = @"TextCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:TextCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:TextCellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    NSDictionary* item = [rssItems objectAtIndex: (indexPath.row-1)/2];

    //article preview
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:11];
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 3;
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.7];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    UIView *backView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
    backView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.backgroundView = backView;

    CGRect f = cell.textLabel.frame;
    [cell.textLabel setFrame: CGRectMake(f.origin.x+15, f.origin.y, f.size.width-15, f.size.height)];
    cell.textLabel.text = [item objectForKey:@"description"];

    return cell;
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (rss.loaded == NO) {
        return [self getLoadingTableCellWithTableView:tableView];
    }

    if (indexPath.row % 2 == 1) {
        return [self getTextCellWithTableView:tableView atIndexPath:indexPath];
    }

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TitleCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    UIView *backView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
    backView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.backgroundView = backView;

    NSDictionary* item = [rssItems objectAtIndex: indexPath.row/2];

    cell.textLabel.text = [item objectForKey:@"title"];

    return cell;
}



/*
 // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
 - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
 return YES;
 }
 */


/*
 // Override to support editing the table view.
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
 // Delete the row from the data source.
 [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
 }   
 else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
 // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
 }   
 }
 */


/*
 // Override to support rearranging the table view.
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
 }
 */


/*
 // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
 - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
 return YES;
 }
 */


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

    //DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    detailViewController.item = [rssItems objectAtIndex:floor(indexPath.row/2)];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    [detailViewController release];
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Memory management

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Relinquish ownership any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Relinquish ownership of anything that can be recreated in viewDidLoad or on demand.
    // For example: self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [rssItems release];
    rssItems = nil;

    [rss release];
    rss = nil;

    [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark RSSLoaderDelegate
-(void)updatedFeedWithRSS:(NSMutableArray*)items
{
    rssItems = [items retain];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

-(void)failedFeedUpdateWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    //
}

@end
```

If you want more information just say it to me by answers and I will edit my question and then you will edit your answer.

I would really appreciate you help.

Comment: SIGABRT means an exception was triggered. The console log will print the exact exception message, and you need to look at that (post it here).

Comment: Hey, you forgot to add your Xcode project files and the xib XML files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are trying to load a XIB named `DetailViewController`, but no such XIB exists or it's not member of your current target.

Comment: To add to this answer - you can Ctrl-Click then remove the outlet. It was nowhere in my code and this is the only way I could delete it. Not even Product > Clean worked.

Answer (score 11):

SIGABRT means in general that there is an uncaught exception. There should be more information on the console.

Answer (score 0):

SIGABRT is, as stated in other answers, a general uncaught exception. You should definitely learn a little bit more about Objective-C. The problem is probably in your UITableViewDelegate method didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I can't tell you much more until you show us something of the code where you handle the table data source and delegate methods.

Comment: How come you think it's a table view that's causing the problem when the exception talks about not being able to load a NIB?

Comment: Because, this happens when you tap the table view cell. But I noticed one more thing - how exactly are you presenting the new view controller? If there is a need of specifying the bundle, make sure you have there [NSBundle mainBundle]. And also it can be an error in compiling and building. Check your XIB if it has the right target and try cleaning (Command+Shift+K) and build cleaning (Command+Shift+Alt+K). It would be great if we could see the part of the code where you fetch the rss and handle the touches. (at least some part of it)